# restrict access on file with php in apache

Tags: php, apache

I have a site on apache web server. 
I have a file structure like this.

```
test.php
accessA.php
otherfiles.php
```

I want to add restrict access to `test.php` file for all user and for all file .for example if a user enter the `http://site/test.php` as url or a file or a user want to access the `site/test.php` directory the error message show and the user can not access the `testA.php`.
but I want allow only accessA.php file for access the test.php file with include statement like this.
accessA.php

```
<?php
include_once 'test.php' ;
?>
```

In other words I want allow access the `test.php` file only for `accessA.php`.
how I do that??

can I use open_basedir ??

Comment: In the first lines of `text.php` test a user account against a set of known permissions. If the user does not have the proper permissions, send a 303.

Comment: can I use open_basedir ??

Comment: I don't get what are you really asking. Please make the question more clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use open_basedir, it's a configuration who permit to chroot the apache's instance (who make the root of the website at the level where you definined it in open base dir variable)
The better way to deny the acces to some page is to do a htaccess

Answer (score 1):

put on top the test.php file this line :

```
if($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']=='test.php')die('not allowed');
```

You can deny access by htaccess rules too.

```
RewriteRule ^test.php$ - [R=404,L]
```

Comment: in this case how I can access to test.php with accessA.php ??

Comment: if you include `test.php` from `accessA.php` the script name will be `accessA.php` not `test.php` so you will be able to include `test.php`